# AndroidTwitterLogin.run crashes in Log.i line NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, oauth, jtwitter, android-log

I am trying to get a simple Android app to work for Twitter.
I am using the library jtwitter.
I am trying to use the AndroidTwitterLogin class.
I have a button to authenticate using OAuth. It calls this code.

```
public void authorizeApp(View v) {
    AndroidTwitterLogin atl = new AndroidTwitterLogin(this,
            MY_TWITTER_KEY,MY_TWITTER_SECRET,MY_TWITTER_CALLBACK) {

        protected void onSuccess(Twitter jtwitter, String[] tokens) {
            jtwitter.setStatus("I can now post to Twitter using my android app !");
            Log.i("TwitterOAuth","successfully authorized app");
            authorizeText.setText("Authorized");

            // Recommended: store tokens in your app for future use
            // with the constructor OAuthSignpostClient(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String accessToken, String accessTokenSecret)
        }
    };
    atl.run();
}
```

At runtime when I get to the AndroidTwitterLogin.run line it crashes with the following code.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method i(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Landroid/util/Log; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.util.Log' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)  
at winterwell.jtwitter.android.AndroidTwitterLogin.run(AndroidTwitterLogin.java:78)  
at com.franksapps.twitteroauth.TwitterActivity.authorizeApp(TwitterActivity.java:45)`
```

Does anyone know if this class is useable in jtwitter/Android or what to do to make this useable?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check which libraries you're including in your app?

The JTwitter download contains a dummy library, which is used to allow it to compile with or without Android. You want to avoid (maybe just delete) the following files: `android.jar`, `android-dummy.jar`. If one of them got included by accident, then it would cause issues.

NB: I confess I haven't used this particular class for a couple of years.

- Daniel